# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I am writing a bot for Discord in Python (discordbot.py 0.2.3a3). I need a bot to play music.

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
from discord.utils import get
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()



async def audio_player_task():
    while True:
        play_next_song.clear()
        current = await songs.get()
        current.start()
        await play_next_song.wait()


def toggle_next():
    bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(play_next_song.set)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not bot.voice_clients(ctx.message.guild):
        voice = await bot.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    else:
       voice = bot.voice_client_in(ctx.message.guild)

    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url, after=toggle_next)
    await songs.put(player)

bot.loop.create_task(audio_player_task())
```

When I try to play music, I get the following error on line 25 of the code above:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: if not bot.voice_clients(ctx.message.guild):

Comment: According to [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) `voice_clients` is not a function but rather a list.

Answer (score 0):

Do u install discord.py or discordbot.py?

**discordbot** is an extension of  **discord**
I guess the problem it's the package that u used.

**Try :**

```
$ pip install -U discord.py
```

**If not, make sure that the .json file is correctly configured**

Answer (score 0):

`bot.voice_clients` is a list.  You can access the voice client of the bot in the guild by using [`ctx.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client)

```
if ctx.voice_client is not None:
```

Comment: Now on the line "voice = bot.voice_client_in (ctx.message.guild)" it gives an error: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'voice_client_in'. If I change to "voice = ctx.voice_client (ctx.message.guild)", I get the following error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [basic voice example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) from the discord.py repository and abandoning discordbot.py.  It looks like that project hasn't been updated in a long time, and discord.py has gone through several breaking changes since then.